# Is there a utility for Windows that can be used to throttle network traffic/induce dropped packages?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I am attempting to simulate the behavior of my application under less than favourable conditions. Is there a tool that allows me to slow down my network connection by capping bandwidth, introducing latency, dropping packages etc? I would prefer it to work on the IP level but it would be acceptable for my current test if it did it on the TCP or HTTP level.